# Parse data using BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to parse data from a website: http://www.sarkari-naukri.in/jobs-by-qualification/b-tech/sub-centre-manager.html

Most of tutorial for BeautifulSoup are for parsing links and not in-depth parsing of required data from a link.

Now i went through some tutorial of BeautifulSoup module of python and wrote this script to download required data string from

```
 <div id="content_box">
        <div id="content" class="hfeed">...
```

Script i'm using:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

def main():
    url = "http://www.sarkari-naukri.in/jobs-by-qualification/b-tech/sub-centre-manager.html"
    data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    bs = BeautifulSoup(data)

    postdata = bs.find('div', {'id': 'content_box'})
    postdata= [s.getText().strip() for s in postdata.findAll('div', {'class':'scdetail'})]

    fname = 'postdata.txt'
    with open(fname, 'w') as outf:
        outf.write('\n'.join(postdata))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

But this script doesn't perform what i expect. I want to get post data into file like wise:

*Title: Vacancy For Sub Centre Manager In National Institute of Electronics and Information Technology – Chandigarh*

*Sub Centre Manager*

*National Institute of Electronics and Information Technology*

*Address: NIELIT, Chandigarh SCO: 114-116 Sector 17B*

*Postal Code: 160017*

*City Chandigarh* and so on....

Please help or suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses BeautifulSoup

```
import os
import sys

# Import System libraries
import re
import urllib2

# Import Custom libraries
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, Tag

job_location = lambda x: x.name == "div" and set([(u"id", u"content")]) <= set(x.attrs)
job_title_location = lambda x: set([(u"class", u"schema_title"), (u"itemprop", u"title")]) <= set(x.attrs)
organ_location = lambda x: set([(u"class", u"schema_hiringorganization"), (u"itemprop", u"name")]) <= set(x.attrs)
details_key_location = lambda x: x.name == "div" and bool(re.search("s.*heading", dict(x.attrs).get(u"class", "")))

def coll_up(ilist,base=0,count=0):
    '''
    Recursively collapse nested lists at depth base and above
    '''
    tlist = []
    if(isinstance(ilist,list) or isinstance(ilist,tuple)):
        for q in ilist:
            tlist += coll_up(q,base,count+1)
    else:
        if(base > count):
            tlist = ilist
        else:
            tlist = [ilist]
    return [tlist] if((count != 0) and (base > count)) else tlist

def info_extract(ilist, count=0):
    '''
    Recursively walk a nested list and upon finding a non iterable, return its string
    '''
    tlist = []
    if(isinstance(ilist, list)):
        for q in ilist:
            if(isinstance(q, Tag)):
                tlist += info_extract(q.contents, count+1)
            else:
                extracted_str = q.strip()
                if(extracted_str):
                    tlist += [extracted_str]
    return [tlist] if(count != 0) else tlist

def main():
    url = "http://www.sarkari-naukri.in/jobs-by-qualification/b-tech/sub-centre-manager.html"
    data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

    job_tags = soup.findAll(job_location)
    if(job_tags):
        job_tag = job_tags[0]
        job_title = info_extract(job_tag.findAll(job_title_location))[0]
        organ = info_extract(job_tag.findAll(organ_location))[0]
        details = coll_up(info_extract(job_tag.findAll(details_key_location)), 2)

        combined_dict = dict([tuple(["Job Title:"] + job_title)] + [tuple(["Organisation:"] + organ)] + [tuple(detail) for detail in details])
        combined_list = [["Job Title:"] + job_title, ["Organisation:"] + organ] + details
        postdata = [" ".join(x) for x in combined_list]
        print postdata

        fname = "postdata.txt"
        with open(fname, "w") as outf:
            outf.write("\n".join(postdata).encode("utf8"))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here: `postdata.findAll('div', {'class': 'scdetail'})`. While you are looking for `div`s, the page has `span`s. Changing it to `postdata.findAll('span', {'class': 'scdetail'})` results in a non-empty result.

Example of one of the values you are wanting to read:

```
<div class="scheading">
    "Pay Scale: " <span class="scdetail" itemProp="baseSalary">Rs. 15,000/-</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This pyparsing extractor will pick out the matching div/span tags:

```
from pyparsing import makeHTMLTags, withAttribute, SkipTo

"""
sample:
<div class="scheading">Postal Code: <span class="scdetail" 
    itemprop="postalCode">160017</span></div>
"""
div,divEnd = makeHTMLTags("div")
span,spanEnd = makeHTMLTags("span")
div.setParseAction(withAttribute(("class","scheading")))
span.setParseAction(withAttribute(("class","scdetail")))

patt = (div + SkipTo(span)("label") + span + SkipTo(spanEnd)("value") + 
            spanEnd + divEnd)

attrs = {}
for match in patt.searchString(html):
    attrs[match.itemprop] = (match.label[0].strip(), match.value)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(attrs.items())
```

prints:

```
[('skills',
  ('Desired Skills:',
   'Preference will be given to candidates having good knowledge of UNIX &amp; Visual FoxPro.')),
 ('qualifications',
  ('Qualifications:',
   '\x91A\x92 level of DOEACC / PGDCA with 2 years experience. ')),
 ('educationRequirements',
  ('Educational Requirements:',
   'B. E. / B. Tech. (CS / IT / Electronics) / MCA / M. Sc. (CS / IT / Electronics) / \x91B\x92 level of DOEACC ')),
 ('addressLocality', ('City', 'Chandigarh')),
 ('addressRegion', ('State', 'Haryana and Punjab')),
 ('streetAddress', ('Address:', 'NIELIT, Chandigarh SCO: 114-116 Sector 17B')),
 ('postalCode', ('Postal Code:', '160017')),
 ('baseSalary', ('Pay Scale:', 'Rs. 15,000/-'))]
```